# In unity is there a clean way to switch (enable/disable) Mesh and Box colliders with a Rigidbody? (3d)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, collider

I am currently working on a classical fps game, I want to be able to generate larger numbers "enemies", ideally in the hundreds. Though this may not be feasible. I am hoping to use physics and `Rigidbod[ies]` for these enemy models.

Obviously the nice solution would be to have `mesh colliders` on all these models but I'm pretty sure that will affect performance. So my alternative idea was to instead set them up initially with box colliders while they are atleast X distance from the player and then once they enter that radius around the player to switch (via enabling and disabling) these box colliders to mesh colliders.

Is this possible to do and what are the implications? My initial tests caused the model to lose its collision detection with the floor, and so drop through the environment.

Are there are performance implications to switching (enabling/disabling) colliders/if this would even make a difference?

Lastly if none of the above, is there a better solution to this problem that is performant?

Comment: Could you show how you switched the colliders? I would have already both on the object and only enable/disable them

Comment: Thanks for the comment derHugo - I need to edit my question, I was enabling/disabling them yes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common practice I know is using multiple primitive colliders under the same rigidbody; I believe this is much more efficient than using mesh colliders, plus, as an added bonus you can even very easily handle special hits (headshots do x2 damage, leg shots slow enemies down) since you know exactly which collider was hit.

Here is an example of how they did it back in the day in Counter Strike
[image]

Notice that you will have to place each primitive collider correctly on the bone structure for it to move correctly during animations.

Comment: This is actually exactly the answer I found when looking at Ragdoll physics, I think adding a ragdoll to my models and animating them is how to be do this :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have two colliders for your ennemies :

1) A persistant box for physical interaction. (This collider would be on a separate layer, colliding only with the physical space.

2) Then, you would have your flexible box / mesh collider. Instead of swapping colliders, **enable/disable** them. If it is too far, try enabling the box, and if too close, enable the mesh collider. I think enabling and disabling is better for performance than removing and adding components at runtime. Plus, since you already have an 'environmental collider', swapping isn't an issue for the movement of your ennemies.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Roman B, that makes perfect sense actually, have a separate box for environment etc. 

I was actually enabling them and disabling them, my wording in the question was poor. Thank you though I think this answers it!